# Tracking IP on a network

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, network-protocols

I need to know the ip addresses visiting my server (Windows Server 2003).  **Scenario** - The clients are accessing a particular tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Wireshark to record all the details about incoming and outgoing connection (IP, ports, packages, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark or [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) ([NetMon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451296(v=vs.85).aspx)).
If your server is behind a NAT with Port Forwarding, you should use NAT logs to see who accessed your server.
In IIS, there is a way to log the client IP address, I found this: [Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702(v=ws.10).aspx).
You cna also obtain the IP address in your server application, log it, and later analyze it with any log analysis tool.

Comment: Wanted to ask that if is it possible to develop a tool of my own which can do the same thing but with less functionality. Say the ip address, the time and the packets. I mean from where should I start? (Any references or study material)

Comment: I know how to do it in Linux but didn't think about it in Windows, at low level. Maybe in Windows you can consider two possibilities: 1-Using libpcap library installed by Wireshark 2-A high level solution, when you web application receives the HTTP message from IIS (if it is HTTP) you can write code to get the IP and other data and log it. That is easy. Then you can write a tool to read the logs but there are alreayd other free tools out there.